# inkPicture control not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am developing a windows c# application in which i require to use inkPicture control.
I am using visual studio 2008.
I tried the following option 
Right clicking toolbox-> customize toolbox->in .NET components search inkPicture control but could not find it there.

Another option I tried was
Tools->Options->Windows Forms Designer->Setting property of AutoToolBox Populate to true but even this didnt help.

What is the right way to find inkPicture control ?

Please help.

Comment: Does this control actually exists in visual studio ?

Comment: he ass kontahi control nahi (at least mazya mahitit tari nahi)...tumhala user control tayar karav lagel

Comment: msdn websites say there exists a control saying this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695541(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: externally bahutek download karun use karav lagel